# Implement a Stack Using Linked List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, stack

I am trying to implement Stack Using Linked List but whenever I try to use any functionality it returns an extra `None` with it. I don't know why it's happening. My desired output should not contain the keyword `None` after every Operation. Can Somebody let me know what's wrong here?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = None
        self.__count = 0


    def push(self, ele):
        newNode = Node(ele)
        newNode.next = self.__head
        self.__head = newNode
        self.__count = self.__count + 1
    

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty() is  True:
            print("Hey! The stack is Empty")
            return
        else:
            pop = self.__head.data
            self.__head = self.__head.next
            self.__count = self.__count - 1
            return pop
        
    

    def top(self):
        if self.isEmpty() is  True:
            print("Hey! The stack is Empty")
            return
        else:
            pop = self.__head.data
            print(pop)
    

    def size(self):
        return self.__count

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.__count == 0

s = Stack()
s.push(15)
print(s.top())
s.push(16)
print(s.pop())
print(s.top())
```

**Output**

15

None

16

None

16

15

None

Comment: It's because `s.top()` does not return anything.  You're printing what it returns, which is None.  In general, it's better to have the function just return a value, and let the caller decide what to do with it, like print it.  That is, remove the print statements from your functions.

Comment: (And change those print statements to return statements, in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Since you just print the top value, `None` is always returned by your `top` function. Change it to *return* the top value instead of printing it:

```
    def top(self):
        if self.isEmpty() is  True:
            print("Hey! The stack is Empty")
            return
        else:
            return self.__head.data
```